# text-align:center equivalent for iPad

Tags: ipad, html, css, safari

I am designing an html5 website for iPad. In the website there are 2 paragraphs as follows:

```
<section id="desc">             
  <p id="title-text"></p>
  <p id="alt-text"></p>
</section>
```

Whose text I want horizontally center of the screen. The text inside the "title-text" and "alt-text" will be filled dynamically at run-time by JavaScript and could change thus width and height have been set to auto and not a static value.

On setting width as auto, it takes the width of the section as well as that of paragraph to be 100%, thus

```
 margin:0 auto;
```

does not work.

I have tried

```
text-align:center;
```

but it does not work in iPad Safari(works on desktop Safari).

Please Help! What should I do?

P.S.- Already tried the

```
align="center"
```

and the < center > tag, which by the way is depreciated in HTML5, but to no avail.

Comment: Make an http://jsfiddle.net that shows your issue

Comment: Here you go Michael Robinson but I do not know how it is going to help as the processing will be done by the jsfiddle engine instead of the iPad. 

http://jsfiddle.net/ZRXRH/

Note: the ABC and XYZ is random text and will be replaced by actual data using JavaScript.